# android studio portrait vs landscape issue

Tags: android-studio-2.0

[screenshot of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDPJp.png)

I am receiving a rendering error stating the surrounding layout did not actually include this layout ONLY in the portrait mode. Landscape mode works fine. I noticed that the landscape is pointing to land/contentmain.xml (as seen in screenshot) but not in portrait mode. I have spent hours attempting to get the portrait view to point to the same thing, but I cannot figure it out. Anyone?

thanks.

(I have latest version of android studio - Feb. 2016)

Answer (score -1):

Copy the code in `activity_main.xml` (**land**) and paste it on `activity_main.xml`. It worked!

EDIT: I believe that was an error on API 23 preview, changing the preview could do the trick.
Also, if you come across an `activity_main.xml`  and an `activity_main.xml` (land), you can always delete the one with land on its name.